# LWP::Simple 6.53 fails to install

Tags: perl, cpan, lwp

I am installing VEP:

```
perl INSTALL.pl
```

During the download of cache file, interruption occured  at:

```
downloading ftp://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-103/variation/indexed_vep_cache/homo_sapiens_refseq_vep_103_GRCh38.tar.gz
Unable to close datastream at INSTALL.pl line 1240.
curl failed (150), trying to fetch using LWP::Simple
```

So, I tried to install LWP::Simple via CPAN, but no luck:

```
nolock_cpan> install LWP::Simple
Running install for module 'LWP::Simple'
Checksum for /home/admin1/.cpan/sources/authors/id/O/OA/OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.53.tar.gz ok
Configuring O/OA/OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.53.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for libwww::perl
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.53.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- OK
Running make for O/OA/OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.53.tar.gz
cp lib/LWP/Protocol/cpan.pm blib/lib/LWP/Protocol/cpan.pm
cp lib/LWP/Protocol/loopback.pm blib/lib/LWP/Protocol/loopback.pm
cp lib/LWP/Protocol/gopher.pm blib/lib/LWP/Protocol/gopher.pm
cp lib/LWP/DebugFile.pm blib/lib/LWP/DebugFile.pm
cp lib/LWP/Authen/Ntlm.pm blib/lib/LWP/Authen/Ntlm.pm
cp lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm blib/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm
cp lib/LWP/Debug/TraceHTTP.pm blib/lib/LWP/Debug/TraceHTTP.pm
cp lib/LWP.pm blib/lib/LWP.pm
cp lib/LWP/Debug.pm blib/lib/LWP/Debug.pm
cp lib/LWP/Protocol/ftp.pm blib/lib/LWP/Protocol/ftp.pm
cp lib/LWP/ConnCache.pm blib/lib/LWP/ConnCache.pm
cp lib/LWP/MemberMixin.pm blib/lib/LWP/MemberMixin.pm
cp lib/LWP/Protocol/data.pm blib/lib/LWP/Protocol/data.pm
cp lib/LWP/Protocol/http.pm blib/lib/LWP/Protocol/http.pm
cp lib/LWP/Authen/Digest.pm blib/lib/LWP/Authen/Digest.pm
cp lwptut.pod blib/lib/libwww/lwptut.pod
cp lib/LWP/Protocol/nntp.pm blib/lib/LWP/Protocol/nntp.pm
cp lib/LWP/Protocol/file.pm blib/lib/LWP/Protocol/file.pm
cp lib/LWP/Protocol/mailto.pm blib/lib/LWP/Protocol/mailto.pm
cp lib/LWP/Protocol.pm blib/lib/LWP/Protocol.pm
cp lwpcook.pod blib/lib/libwww/lwpcook.pod
cp lib/LWP/Protocol/nogo.pm blib/lib/LWP/Protocol/nogo.pm
cp lib/LWP/Simple.pm blib/lib/LWP/Simple.pm
cp lib/LWP/RobotUA.pm blib/lib/LWP/RobotUA.pm
cp lib/LWP/Authen/Basic.pm blib/lib/LWP/Authen/Basic.pm
cp bin/lwp-download blib/script/lwp-download
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::MY -e 'MY->fixin(shift)' -- blib/script/lwp-download
cp bin/lwp-dump blib/script/lwp-dump
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::MY -e 'MY->fixin(shift)' -- blib/script/lwp-dump
cp bin/lwp-mirror blib/script/lwp-mirror
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::MY -e 'MY->fixin(shift)' -- blib/script/lwp-mirror
cp bin/lwp-request blib/script/lwp-request
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::MY -e 'MY->fixin(shift)' -- blib/script/lwp-request
Manifying 4 pod documents
Manifying 11 pod documents
  OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.53.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/usr/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t t/base/*.t t/base/protocols/*.t t/leak/*.t t/local/*.t t/robot/*.t
t/00-report-prereqs.t .......... #
# Versions for all modules listed in MYMETA.json (including optional ones):
#
# === Configure Requires ===
#
#     Module                       Want     Have
#     ------------------------ -------- --------
#     CPAN::Meta::Requirements 2.120620    2.140
#     ExtUtils::MakeMaker           any     7.24
#     File::Copy                    any     2.32
#     Getopt::Long                  any     2.49
#     Module::Metadata              any 1.000033
#
# === Build Requires ===
#
#     Module              Want Have
#     ------------------- ---- ----
#     ExtUtils::MakeMaker  any 7.24
#
# === Test Requires ===
#
#     Module                 Want     Have
#     ---------------------- ---- --------
#     ExtUtils::MakeMaker     any     7.24
#     File::Spec              any     3.67
#     FindBin                 any     1.51
#     HTTP::Daemon           6.12     6.12
#     Test::Fatal             any    0.016
#     Test::More             0.96 1.302183
#     Test::Needs             any 0.002006
#     Test::RequiresInternet  any     0.05
#
# === Test Recommends ===
#
#     Module              Want     Have
#     --------------- -------- --------
#     CPAN::Meta      2.120900 2.150010
#     Test::LeakTrace      any     0.17
#
# === Runtime Requires ===
#
#     Module                Want    Have
#     --------------------- ---- -------
#     Digest::MD5            any    2.55
#     Encode                2.12    2.88
#     Encode::Locale         any    1.05
#     File::Listing            6    6.04
#     HTML::Entities         any    3.69
#     HTML::HeadParser       any    3.71
#     HTTP::Cookies            6    6.04
#     HTTP::Date               6    6.02
#     HTTP::Negotiate          6    6.00
#     HTTP::Request            6    6.14
#     HTTP::Request::Common    6    6.14
#     HTTP::Response           6    6.14
#     HTTP::Status          6.07    6.14
#     IO::Select             any    1.22
#     IO::Socket             any    1.38
#     LWP::MediaTypes          6    6.02
#     MIME::Base64           2.1    3.15
#     Net::FTP              2.58    3.10
#     Net::HTTP             6.18    6.20
#     Scalar::Util           any 1.46_02
#     Try::Tiny              any    0.30
#     URI                   1.10    1.73
#     URI::Escape            any    3.31
#     WWW::RobotRules          6    6.01
#     base                   any    2.26
#     strict                 any    1.11
#     warnings               any    1.37
#
# === Runtime Suggests ===
#
#     Module               Want Have
#     -------------------- ---- ----
#     Authen::NTLM         1.02 1.09
#     Data::Dump           1.13 1.23
#     IO::Socket::INET      any 1.35
#     LWP::Protocol::https 6.02 6.07
#
t/00-report-prereqs.t .......... ok
t/10-attrs.t ................... ok
t/base/default_content_type.t .. # Some tests for the PUT/PATCH methods can only be run on
# HTTP::Request version 6.07/6.12 or higher.
# If your version isn't good enough, we'll skip those.
# Your version is 6.14 and that's good enough
t/base/default_content_type.t .. ok
t/base/protocols.t ............. ok
t/base/protocols/nntp.t ........ skipped: nntp.perl.org is unstable and Test::RequiresInternet is not catching it
t/base/proxy.t ................. ok
t/base/simple.t ................ ok
t/base/ua.t .................... ok
t/base/ua_handlers.t ........... ok
t/leak/no_leak.t ............... ok
t/local/autoload-get.t ......... ok
t/local/autoload.t ............. ok
t/local/get.t .................. ok
t/local/http.t ................. ok
t/local/httpsub.t .............. ok
t/local/protosub.t ............. ok
t/redirect.t ................... 1/?
#   Failed test '... and has tells us about the problem'
#   at t/redirect.t line 39.
#                   'read timeout at /usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1/Net/HTTP/Methods.pm line 268.
# '
#     doesn't match '(?^i:Can't connect)'
t/redirect.t ................... 3/?
#   Failed test '... and has tells us about the problem'
#   at t/redirect.t line 56.
#                   'read timeout at /usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1/Net/HTTP/Methods.pm line 268.
# '
#     doesn't match '(?^i:Can't connect)'
# Looks like you failed 2 tests of 4.
t/redirect.t ................... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 2/4 subtests
t/robot/ua-get.t ............... ok
t/robot/ua.t ................... ok

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/redirect.t                 (Wstat: 512 Tests: 4 Failed: 2)
  Failed tests:  2, 4
  Non-zero exit status: 2
Files=19, Tests=270, 17 wallclock secs ( 0.11 usr  0.04 sys +  2.05 cusr  0.30 csys =  2.50 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/19 test programs. 2/270 subtests failed.
Makefile:1005: recipe for target 'test_dynamic' failed
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.53.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.53.tar.gz
Failed during this command:
 OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.53.tar.gz              : make_test NO
```

I am using UBUNTU 20.0.4, tried via sudo as well. During the installation of LWP::Simple, some dependencies are missing, e.g., Authen::NTLM which I installed and is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been reported before. See https://github.com/libwww-perl/libwww-perl/issues/370

The workaround suggested in that discussion is to set `NO_NETWORK_TESTING` to a true value before starting the installation.